Enabling cypress parallelization on a windows virtual machine
How can I modify the following yml file in github actions to enable parallelization in cypress but have the tests run in an orderly manner? I mean I managed to enable parallelization but the virtual machines sometimes test the same tests, on two virtual machines the same test intersects. I don't know how to separate them. I mention that this action is based on a virtual machine with windows.
Let's say there are 90 tests in my test folder, and I need 3 virtual machines to do 22 tests each and another 24.
I have this YML file:
name: UP Automation regression

on:
  push:
    branches: [ Alex ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ Alex ]

jobs:
  run-automation-regression-tests:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - run: git config --global url."https://TOKEN".insteadOf https://github.com/
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: electron
          record: true
          parallel: false
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}


An option could be to the github actions matrix strategy concept. However, you would still need to manage the tests division in the workflow, before generating the matrix. An option could be to have different folders for each group of test, and use each folder path in the matrix strategy, to run the cypress test separately for each folder.
